# Dynamically spawn 'X' number of queues in python

Tags: python, queue

i need to spawn 'x' number of queues in python

```
q1 = Queue(maxsize = 0)
q2 = Queue(maxsize = 0)
.
.

qn = Queue(maxsize = 0)
```

what is the pythonic way to do it ?

Comment: List of `Queue`s? by the way `maxsize=0` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
for i in range(10):
    locals()["q" + str(i)] = Queue(maxsize=0)

print(q1)
```

Output:

```
<queue.Queue object at 0x00000163554B6220>
```

Comment: on doing that i get a ``` [<queue.Queue object at 0x00000163554B6220>, <queue.Queue object at 0x00000163554B64F0>, <queue.Queue object at 0x00000163554B6790>]```    i need somehitng like q1 = queue object, q2 = queue object and so on

Comment: yeah if you want to use one of them you can access by `q[n]`. helpful?

Comment: i could but something like queue_txmessages , queue_rxmessages, queue_dropped messages makes better sense in my script i think hence i wanted them assigned to individual variables instead in a list

Comment: updated, is that what you want? @omkarjoglekar

Comment: The documentation for [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) clearly states it should not be modified.

Comment: @CC7052 i think it does the job :) thanks

Comment: @martineau what would be the implications of this ? after modifying the locals () ?